# Implementing multiple AuthenticationHandler for different accesstoken

Tags: c#, authentication, access-token

I have a microservice which accepts requests from different clients for which it uses different accesstoken to authenticate each client.
To do this I have created an `AccessTokenAuthenticationHandler` which implements the `AuthenticationHandler<AccessTokenAuthenticationOptions>` interface.

The `AccessTokenAuthenticationOptions` looks like this:

```
public class AccessTokenAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

In my `StartUp.cs` I use the following code to configure the different types of authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = SchemesNamesConst.TokenAuthenticationDefaultScheme;
})
.AddScheme<AccessTokenAuthenticationOptions, AccessTokenAuthenticationHandler>(
    SchemesNamesConst.TokenAuthenticationClientOneScheme, o =>
    {
        o.AccessToken = _clientOneAuthenticationSettings.AccessToken;
    })
.AddScheme<AccessTokenAuthenticationOptions, AccessTokenAuthenticationHandler>(
    SchemesNamesConst.TokenAuthenticationClientTwoScheme, o =>
    {
        o.AccessToken = _clientTwoAuthenticationSettings.AccessToken;
    });
```

Above each controller that I want to authenticate the requests for `ClientOne` I have added the following attribute:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = SchemesNamesConst.TokenAuthenticationClientOneScheme)]
```

In my `AccessTokenAuthenticationHandler` I fetch the accesstoken from the HttpHeader and compare it to `AccessToken` in the injected `OptionsMonitor`:

```
public class AccessTokenAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AccessTokenAuthenticationOptions>
{
    public AccessTokenAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AccessTokenAuthenticationOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var headers = Request.Headers;
        if (!headers.TryGetValue("X-Auth-Token", out var headerToken)
            || string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerToken))
        {
            return Task.FromResult (AuthenticateResult.Fail ("Token not found"));
        }

        string accessToken = OptionsMonitor.CurrentValue.AccessToken; //AccessToken is null
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accessToken))
        {
            return Task.FromResult (AuthenticateResult.Fail ("Token not defined"));
        }

        //Some more code to compare the two token and handle it accordingly
    }
}
```

The problem is that at runtime `OptionsMonitor.CurrentValue.AccessToken` is always `null`.
What am I doing wrong?